# how to Read headers of a CSV file in Snowflake stage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am learning snowflake ,I was [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RvsY.png) trying to read the headers of CSV file stored in aws bucket ..I used the metadata fields that required me to input $1,$2 as column names and so on to obtain headers(for copy into table creation)..

is there a better alternative to this?

Statement :

```
select 
  Top 100 metadata$filename, 
  metadata$file_row_number, 
  t.$1, 
  t.$2, 
  t.$3, 
  t.$4, 
  t.$5, 
  t.$6 
from 
  @aws_stage t 
where 
  metadata$filename = 'OrderDetails.csv'
```

Comment: Better in what way? Do you want to select all of them at once?

Comment: yes .. like we use "select * from table'

Comment: In the file format, tell it not to skip the first row. Select * limit 1 will be the column names.

Comment: Have you tried `t.*` instead of `t.$1, 
  t.$2, 
  t.$3, 
  t.$4, 
  t.$5, 
  t.$6 `?